# How to config WebApp in Tomcat (Eclipse Galileo)?

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, tomcat, eclipse-wtp

I reinstalled my Eclipse, installed all the plugins and so my Tomcat configs are missing too. The Maven project import went well, but now i can't start the Tomcat server. It doesn't find the WebApp configuration.xml and the lf4j.xml files... Where can i tell the server where this files are? This files are in a separeted directory.

Thank you very much!!

Comment: In a *tomcat* configuration there are no files called 'configuration.xml' or 'lf4j.xml'. Probably they are part of the webapp (, which takes care of reading them - not tomcat) or it's Eclipse going nuts. What does "can't start tomcat" mean? Can you post the error?

Comment: I found the way meanwhile... The path to the WebApp config xml must be set in the Tomcat launch configuration (VM arguments).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tomcat launch configuration -> VM arguments -> -Dwebapp.home="C:\path-to-webapp-config\condifuration.xml"